# Assistance with pigpio SPI slave bscXfer on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: spi, pigpio, c++

I am trying to write C code so my Raspberry Pi4 can be an SPI slave, and the SPI master can read data from the Pi4.

I'm expecting to get this data from SPI master (in a continuous loop):

```
0x01 0x42 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I want to reply with this data back from Pi4 slave to SPI master (in a continuous loop too):

```
0xff 0x73 0x5a 0xff 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f
```

I have got this working using bit banging, but now I want to use `bscXfer` http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#bscXfer

My C program is below and the `received 8 bytes: 42:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:` message is promising, as I think that matches the data I'm expecting from master.

My questions are:

- why does the "Transmit Fifo" seem to fill up? It reaches `16` after my second loop and does not accept any more. Do I need to "flush" this Fifo to the master?
- What options can I try to get master reading from this Fifo buffer?
- Sometimes I receive 8 bytes from master, sometimes 15, why?
- Why am I missing that first expected `0x01` byte from master, and getting the second one `0x42` at the start?

I think it has something to do with this from the docs, but I don't quite understand what it means :(

> The BSC slave in SPI mode deserializes data from the MOSI pin into its
> receiver/FIFO when the LSB of the first byte is a 0. No data is output
> on the MISO pin. When the LSB of the first byte on MOSI is a 1, the
> transmitter/FIFO data is serialized onto the MISO pin while all other
> data on the MOSI pin is ignored.

Debug output from my program:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pthread -o spi-test spi-test.c -lpigpio
$ sudo ./spi-test

Tried to reply with 9 bytes: ff:73:5a:ff:7f:7f:7f:7f:7f: read 16 bytes: 42:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:42:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:
Debug Return Status 590338:
 -> RE  receive FIFO empty
 -> 8 in transmit fifo
 -> 0 in receive fifo
 -> 9 copied to transmit fifo

Tried to reply with 9 bytes: ff:73:5a:ff:7f:7f:7f:7f:7f: read 8 bytes: 42:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:
Debug Return Status 525318:
 -> RE  receive FIFO empty
 -> TF  transmit FIFO full
 -> 16 in transmit fifo
 -> 0 in receive fifo
 -> 8 copied to transmit fifo

Tried to reply with 9 bytes: ff:73:5a:ff:7f:7f:7f:7f:7f: read 15 bytes: 42:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:84:0:0:0:0:0:0:
Debug Return Status 1030:
 -> RE  receive FIFO empty
 -> TF  transmit FIFO full
 -> 16 in transmit fifo
 -> 0 in receive fifo
 -> 0 copied to transmit fifo

Tried to reply with 9 bytes: ff:73:5a:ff:7f:7f:7f:7f:7f: read 8 bytes: 42:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:
Debug Return Status 1030:
 -> RE  receive FIFO empty
 -> TF  transmit FIFO full
 -> 16 in transmit fifo
 -> 0 in receive fifo
 -> 0 copied to transmit fifo

Tried to reply with 9 bytes: ff:73:5a:ff:7f:7f:7f:7f:7f: read 15 bytes: 42:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:84:0:0:0:0:0:0:
Debug Return Status 1030:
 -> RE  receive FIFO empty
 -> TF  transmit FIFO full
 -> 16 in transmit fifo
 -> 0 in receive fifo
 -> 0 copied to transmit fifo
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pigpio.h>

#define SEND_BYTE_COUNT 9

bsc_xfer_t xfer;

// These are the 9 bytes of data I would like to send back to SPI master from Pi:
unsigned char dataToSend[SEND_BYTE_COUNT] = {
    0xff, // 1: data always ff
    0x73, // 2: 0x71: 4 = digital, 7 = analog, f = config mode. 1 = how many words follow header
    0x5a, // 3: always 5a for data
    0xff, // 4: button press
    0x7f, //velocityHex, // 5: button press
    0x7f, //positions.speedMultiplier, // 6: joystick
    0x7f, //positions.steering, // 7: joystick
    0x7f, //positions.leftRight, // 8: joystick
    0x7f //positions.forwardBack  // 9: joystick
};

// Helper function to debug the bscXfer return status number:
void debugReturnStatus(int status) {
    printf("Debug Return Status %d:\n", status);
    if(status & 1) {
        printf(" -> TB  transmit busy\n");
    }
    if(status & 1 << 1) {
        printf(" -> RE  receive FIFO empty\n");
    }
    if(status & 1 << 2) {
        printf(" -> TF  transmit FIFO full\n");
    }
    if(status & 1 << 3) {
        printf(" -> RF  receive FIFO full\n");
    }
    if(status & 1 << 4) {
        printf(" -> TE  transmit FIFO empty\n");
    }
    if(status & 1 << 5) {
        printf(" -> RB  receive busy\n");
    }
    int numbBytesInTransmitFifo = ( status & 0x7C0 ) >> 6;
    printf(" -> %d in transmit fifo\n", numbBytesInTransmitFifo);
    int numbBytesInReceiveFifo = ( status & 0xF800 ) >> 11;
    printf(" -> %d in receive fifo\n", numbBytesInReceiveFifo);
    int numbBytesInCopiedToTransmit = ( status & 0x1F0000 ) >> 16;
    printf(" -> %d copied to transmit fifo\n", numbBytesInCopiedToTransmit);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    bool controlOptionsForSending[14] = {
        true,  // EN    enable BSC peripheral
        true, // SP enable SPI mode
        false, // I2    enable I2C mode
        false, // PH    set SPI phase high
        false, // PL    set SPI polarity high
        false, // ES    send status register as first I2C byte
        false, // EC    send control register as first I2C byte
        false, // BK    abort operation and clear FIFOs
        true, // TE enable transmit
        true, // RE enable receive
        false, // IR    invert receive status flags
        false, // TF    enable test FIFO
        false, // HC    enable host control
        false  // IT    invert transmit status flags
    };

    uint32_t controlSending = 0x0;

    for(int c = 0; c < sizeof(controlOptionsForSending); c++){
        if(controlOptionsForSending[c]){
            controlSending = controlSending | (1 << c);
        }
    }

    gpioInitialise();

    xfer.control = controlSending;
    memcpy(xfer.txBuf, dataToSend, SEND_BYTE_COUNT);
    xfer.txCnt = SEND_BYTE_COUNT;

    int loop = 0;
    while(loop++ < 10){
        // Do the SPI slave data transfer.
        // We do this in a loop because I need to send a constant stream of data back to master.
        int status = bscXfer(&xfer);

        if(status > 0){
            printf("Tried to reply with %d bytes: ",xfer.txCnt);
            for(int c = 0; c < xfer.txCnt; c++){
                printf("%x:", xfer.txBuf[c]);
            }
            printf(" read %d bytes: ", xfer.rxCnt);
            for(int c = 0; c < xfer.rxCnt; c++){
                printf("%x:", xfer.rxBuf[c]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            debugReturnStatus(status);
        }
        // If I loop any quicker I seem to lose data and just get 0x0 returned in buffer
        usleep(6000);
    }
    gpioTerminate();
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Milliways I have updated my question to say the master reads from slave, not slave sends to master.